# iOS TestFlight Share Extension Not Installed

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I recently uploaded a TestFlight external test build to iTunes Connect. When users download the application the Share Extension doesn't seem to be appearing in Safari or any other application that has the share menu. Even after clicking the more button the application extension doesn't appear at all.

Any reason why this might be happening? And any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same issue occur with a few of my testers on an early TestFlight build. After I uploaded a new build that had the exact same share extension code it was no longer an issue.

It should be noted that I contacted the original poster about this issue and he had the same experience.

I think this can be attributed to a TestFlight bug that works itself out over multiple builds.

**EDIT**

I found out that one of my users was using iOS 10.2. While the deployment target of my main app was 10.0, **the deployment target of my Extension was at 11.2**. This prevented my share extension from working for them.

Lesson: Make sure your deployment targets are the appropriately set across all your targets!